# Is it possible to do a demo with testnet without buying EOS RAM?

Tags: eosio.token, ram, development, ram-allocation

I'm a rookie when it comes to developing Dapps. I'm thinking of doing a project using EOSIO. I just need to do a demo to showcase my project so I don't need to deploy it for others to use.

I don't have enough money to buy EOS RAM. So, I have some questions about the cost of a EOSIO project:

1. Does it cost money to use EOSIO testnet to create test users for demonstration purposes only?
2. Is it possible to hook up EOSIO testnet with a frontend website that is online for demo purpose only?

Answer (score 0):

On the testnet, RAM is costs fake-EOS, and you can get that for free from the faucet on the appropriate testnet website.

So yes, it is possible to set up a EOSIO dApp on the testnet without it costing any money, and it is also possible to hook up the testnet with a frontend website.